# Unix programming in C , expression must be modifiable lvalue

Tags: c, unix, stat, lvalue

So I am trying to write this code to implements some function that is supposed to get permission of a file in unix programming.
t

```
char* getFilePremissions(struct stat* buff){
char* retStr = malloc(SIZE_OF_PREM_BITS+1); /* Allocating 10 bits for string to be returned */
/* Owner premissions: */

(buff->st_mode & S_IRUSR )== S_IRUSR ? retStr[0] = 'r' : retStr[0] = '-';

((buff->st_mode & S_IWUSR) == S_IWUSR )? retStr[1] = 'w' :retStr[1] = '-';


if((buff->st_mode & S_IXUSR) == S_IXUSR ) retStr[2] = 'x';
else retStr[2] = '-';


/* Group premissions */

if((buff->st_mode & S_IRGRP) == S_IRGRP ) retStr[3] = 'r';
else retStr[3] = '-';

if((buff->st_mode & S_IWGRP) == S_IWGRP ) retStr[4] = 'w';
else retStr[4] = '-';
```

Wherever it is written with simple "If" and "else" condition it works.
but the lines :

```
(buff->st_mode & S_IRUSR )== S_IRUSR ? retStr[0] = 'r' : retStr[0] = '-';

((buff->st_mode & S_IWUSR) == S_IWUSR )? retStr[1] = 'w' :retStr[1] = '-';
```

giving me warning above - "expression must be modifiable lvalue"

any ideas why?

thanks

Comment: The operator precedence of the ternary is higher than that of the assignment (so that the more idiomatic `i = cond ? 1 : 2;` works without parentheses). Try putting the assignments in parentheses, like `(buff->st_mode & S_IRUSR ) == S_IRUSR ? (retStr[0] = 'r') : (retStr[0] = '-');` . Also, because your use is not idiomatic in C (probably more like Perl or such) I'd advise against using it.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica can you give an example on my code? because I think I've tried this already

Comment: By the way, the idiomatic (and shorter) formulation would be `retStr[1] = (buff->st_mode & S_IWUSR) == S_IWUSR ? 'w' : '-';` Your idea of using the entire assignment as the alternative expressions to the right of the ternary works only because in C assignments are (also) expressions with a value, and because an expression can be a statement (i.e. `i = (a = b);` is perfectly fine (and doesn't need the parentheses, I only added them for emphasis); and also `1;` is a valid statement, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

`?:` has higher operator precedence than `=`, so you can't write code such as

`(buff->st_mode & S_IRUSR )== S_IRUSR ? retStr[0] = 'r' : retStr[0] = '-';`

or it parses along the lines of `retStr[0] = ('r' : retStr[0]) =` which is of course nonsense.

It is simple to fix:

```
retStr[0] = (buff->st_mode & S_IRUSR ) == S_IRUSR ? 'r' : '-';
```

Or better yet:

```
if ((buff->st_mode & S_IRUSR) == S_IRUSR)
  retStr[0] = 'r';
else
  retStr[0] = '-';
```

Avoid using `?:` just for the sake of it, it doesn't necessarily improve readability but it does come with various subtle crap that one can do without. Not just operator precedence, but also implicit promotion of the 2nd and 3rd operands.